# Why is Kirk dressed in Gold?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

After reading [Why is Data's uniform gold and not red?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37267/why-is-datas-uniform-gold-and-not-red) in which it is clearly stated that

> Gold is operations (security, science, engineering, etc.), Red is command.

Why is Kirk dressed in Gold?

Comment: The original series had a different colour scheme: Gold was command, blue was science and red was engineering / expendable.

Comment: Please make an answer from that if you have any reference (wikis included)

Comment: This is just from observation, not something I can absolutely guarantee. I'm not sure if there were other colours.

Comment: I believe Dax and Sisko made comments discussing the color changes in the episode they went back in time to "The Trouble With Tribbles". (Don't recall the episode or the exact quote, which is why this is a comment only.)

Comment: Because he's a smooth operator. Duh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The uniform colour semantics were changed between TOS and TNG. Gold [indicated](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%282250s-2260s%29#Department_color_codes) command in TOS and red indicated ["likely to die soon"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Redshirt) .. err ... Operations.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" but the red uniform was only bad if you worked for security. Otherwise wearing a gold uniform was the killer.

Comment: @Richard: Yes, there were also [other casualties](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32483/2565) but the term "red shirt" did become kind of a thing of its own.

Answer (score 12):

Per the DS9 episode "[Trials and Tribble-ations](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/503.htm)";

> "**O'BRIEN:** *Don't you know anything about this period in time?*
>
> **BASHIR:** *I'm a doctor, not an historian.*
>
> **SISKO:** ***In the old days, operations officers wore red, command officers wore gold.***
>
> **DAX:** *And women wore less.*
>
> (Dax pirouettes. The red skirt suits her legs.)
>
> **BASHIR:** *I think I'm going to like history.*

[image]

For more information than anyone could ever reasonably need on Starfleet Uniforms, click [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_uniform)

Comment: I couldn't imagine a better explanatory image.

Comment: @joshbirk - It's such a shame that it's a duplicate question...

Comment: What the devil is going on with Dax's face?

Comment: @joshbirk: Perhaps one that isn't gratuitously misogynistic?